# One case is missing from פרק חרש שנשא

Tags: masechet-yevamot

The end of the fourteenth chapter of *mishnayos Y’vamos* go through cases of two brothers’ marriages. The first cases are where both brothers, or both their wives, are deaf-mutes. Then come the following cases, in this order:

- one brother is a deaf-mute and neither wife is, and the wives are sisters
- one wife is a deaf-mute and neither husband is, and the wives are sisters
- one brother and his wife are deaf-mutes, and the other wife is her sister and not a deaf-mute
- one brother is a deaf-mute and neither wife is, and the wives are not sisters
- one wife is a deaf-mute and neither husband is, and the wives are not sisters
- one brother and his wife are deaf-mutes, and the other wife is not her sister and not a deaf-mute

Why doesn’t it also have the cases that one brother and the other’s wife are deaf-mutes (and the wives are sisters, or are not sisters)? That seems to be the one missing case.

Comment: Isn't that the case where everything is Derabanan? The Mishna only is figuring out how to handle Derabanan when there is also Deorayta aspects (IIRC)

Comment: As @DoubleAA wrote, here his wife is Miderabanan, his Yebama comes from the strrenght of Nisuin derabanan, Both derabanan. Din pashut of Achot Isha as if all is deOrayta.

Comment: But the _mishna_ deals with cases where everything is _d'rabanan_ also. For example, where both brothers are deaf-mutes.

Comment: I’m sure I’ve seen somewhere that this is אורחא דמילתא. If there are a חרש and חרשת and פקח and פקחת, we assume that they married their own “type”. But I can’t track down a source